# why a variable with value 0 is not admited asking if exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Im developing a very big application on Scalable Javascript Aplication Architecture, in the core i have a simple function to asign a css property to a element.

```
establishCSSvalue : function( element, property, value ) {
 if( element && property && value ) {
jQuery( element ).css( property, value );
 } else {
//log wrong arguments
 }
}
```

If the variable value is equal to 0 the if go to the else, if i delete the value condition o fix the 0:

```
if( element && property ) {
if( element && property && ( value || value == 0 ) ) {
```

It works.

Anyone can explain me what its happening, or why? I cant understand or my knowlegde of javascript its not enough, in php is easy with isset. For me a variable with value = 0 exist...

Thanks.

Comment: You have exactly the same problem in PHP if you do `$foo = 0; if($foo) {...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are simply trying to see that all three function arguments actually exist and are not undefined, then you can't just check them for a falsey value as you are.  You must specifically check to see if they are not undefined.

You can do that like this:

```
if (element !== undefined && property !== undefined && value !== undefined)
```

The reason you cannot do this:

```
if (element && property && value)
```

is because any falsey value will cause that statement to fail.  falsey values include `null`, `false`, `0`, `""`, `undefined` and `NaN`.  So, if you ONLY want to check to make sure it's not undefined, then you need to specifically check for that rather than any falsey value.

---

Note: If all you're really trying to tell is whether the caller actually passed three arguments to the function when they called it, you can also check `arguments.length` like this:

```
if (arguments.length === 3)
```

or just check to see that the last variable is not undefined:

```
if (value !== undefined)
```

Comment: isn't better using `typeof` operator?

Comment: @chumkiu - For function arguments, it only makes a difference if you're worried about some rogue piece of code redefining the value of `undefined`.  Otherwise, it doesn't make any difference for function arguments so I use this terminology because it's more compact and seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking and i do the follow. A function for the core class:

```
function isset( variable ) {
    if( variable !== null && variable !== false && variable !== undefined && variable !== NaN  && variable !== "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I was thinking about including "" or not, but i think i will decide in the future.

Now i simple ask for isset(variable), only when i going to make the jquery or the action where i need all the variables with value, previous i can make tricks passing diferents Falsey values in a variables to sometimes get property values from database.

Thanks.

Comment: Much simpler to just do: `if (variable === 0 || variable)`.  Just test for the one falsey value you want to allow rather than all the ones you don't want to allow.

Comment: Yeah but || variable prevents all other Falsey values that are not 0?

Comment: My suggestion generates the same result as your much longer one.  It results in `true` if `variable === 0` or `variable` is not falsey which is just a shorter way of expressing what you wrote.  Same result - much simpler code.